# Aged Debt Report on Sage200 - LinqDataProvider

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, powerbi, sage-erp

Im trying to pull sql script that builds Aged Debt Report on Sage200 Report Designer. This report is out of the box

I have a powerbi model which pulls data from Sage Datawarehouse, however I am struggled to replicate the above report into powerbi because I couldnt access sql behind this report. When open this report in Sage200 Report designer, I could see that the data source is of LinQProvider with the connection string
LinqDataProvider
Sage200Accounts

Data Model=Sage 200 Accounts;Root Path=\SERVERNAME\Sage\REPORTING;Report Types=\SERVERNAME\Sage\REPORTING\DEFAULT\REPORTS\Sage200Accounts.reporttypes;Default Report=\SERVERNAME\Sage\REPORTING\DEFAULT\DEFAULTS\Default.report;Timeout=1800

I couldnt locate where this data model lives or I have enough understanding of how this report connects to the data model.

Anyone with Sage200 experience I would be so grateful if you can advice please? Basically I have access to SQL server datawarehouse, but the above report has some "variables" that somehow were built and saved inside this Data Model.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The report designer is reading the datamodel from %userprofile%\appdata\local\sage\sage200\assembly in Sage.accounting.datamodel.dll

The model source is available on the server however in SLAgedTransaction.cs however it is protected by licence agreement so I can't post it.

In Sage 200 2011 it was possible to use the datamodel through [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) which may still work in the current version.  With this in mind perhaps it would be a better idea to connect PowerBI to the datamodel rather than trying to extract SQL script?  Also take a look at the good work [Pan Intelligence](https://www.panintelligence.com/) are doing with regards to BI reporting